# Dagger-2 is not generating the static component class in KOTLIN - Android

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I am using Dagger-2 to generate the static component class in KOTLIN. Here is the class I am using, but when I am making the project I can't generate the static component class:

```
import javax.inject.Inject


    class Car @Inject constructor(engine: Engine,wheel: Wheel){


        var isCarReady = "Now Car is Ready Vroom!!!!"+engine.isEngineIsReady+wheel.isWheelIsReady


    }


import javax.inject.Inject

class Engine @Inject constructor(){
     val isEngineIsReady = "Engine is ready"


}


import javax.inject.Inject

class Wheel @Inject constructor() {

    var isWheelIsReady = "Wheel is Ready"

}

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.abhijit.simpledagger2demo.depedencies.Car
import javax.inject.Inject

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject lateinit var car : Car

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}

import com.abhijit.simpledagger2demo.MainActivity
import dagger.Component

@Component
interface MakeCarComponent {

    fun inject(activity: MainActivity)


}
```

Here is below my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abhijit.simpledagger2demo"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    kapt {
        generateStubs = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    //add dagger dependencies
    // Dagger Android
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.15"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.15"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.15"


}
```

It's not creating `DaggerMakeCarComponent`. Any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: This is because you never create one. This should be done in Activity's `onCreate()`. You also must have `MakeCarModule`.

Comment: @Onik  i am creating DaggerMakeCarComponent is not finding the class

Comment: Your component DOES NOT HAVE module as I said before, that's the reason.

Comment: Do not `@Inject` before the `Component` is built.

Comment: Can you mention is code i am new to dagger

Comment: @coroutineDispatcher i did the same it seems not working

Comment: what is `kapt {
        generateStubs = true
    }` for?

Comment: I removed it it was not stub generation in kotlin but still the problem persists

Comment: You might want to update your Dagger version for better Kotlin support.

Answer (score 0):

I found you are missing one dependency is in your `build.gradle`.

```
  kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.15"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.15"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.15"
```

Just one more in the last

```
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.15'
```

It should work let me know if you facing any problem